# clickonce what files do I have to keep?

Tags: clickonce, directory

Using ClickOnce each time I create a new version, the full monty is deployed in a Application Folder like:

MyApp_1_0_0_16

MyApp_1_0_0_17
Etc.

And each folder is several megabytes worth.

Can someone tell me wether I can get rid of older versions, or if I must keep lhe penultimate on,e together with the last one.

Are there any caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep any but the most recent two versions. If you are publishing your application and setting the minimum required version, you can just keep the most recent one. (I would always keep at least 2, but then, I'm paranoid. I mean, cautious.)

Note that the deployment manifest in the root (whatever.application) denotes which version the user will run. When you publish a new version, this will contain the most recent deployment manifest, and it is identical to the one in Application Files/yourappname_1_2_3_4 (where 1.2.3.4 is the version). So if you replace the one in the root, you can always get it back by copying it out of the appropriate versioned folder. This is also how you can revert to a different version.

Basically, if you know you're not going to revert to a version, you can delete its folder under Application Files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that the old versions of the files aren't references so you should be able to remove all of the older folders - however, I like you, would keep the last two versions if for no other reason than being able to easily roll back should the need arise.

If you are *really* <strike>paranoid</strike> cautious then start with version one and work forwards slowly double checking at each stage that nothing breaks.

Comment: Thanks.. Your answer bring another question: HOW do you rollback clickonce to the previous version?

Comment: @Didier - You *did* keep a copy of the `<application>.application`, `publish.htm` and `setup.exe` files didn't you? :)

Comment: Nope! It IS replaced each time I do publish. But I WILL KEEP from now on, for sutre! Thanks again.